How to extract the audio stream from an mp4 video file?
Basically I am using this python code but when I put the extracted audio stream below the video stream with the same audio, they don't line up.
One interesting detail is when I used the video editor itself to save the entire audio in the project when I have only the video stream, MP3 format also has a delay/lag but when I used wav format, it matched the audio track of the video 100%. So I thought changing the code to export wav format would do the same but no.
from pydub.utils import mediainfo
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def extractAudioFromVideoFile(inputFile, outputFile, startTimeInSeconds, endTimeInSeconds):
    clip = VideoFileClip(inputFile)
    # Ensure the end time does not exceed the video's duration
    if endTimeInSeconds > clip.duration:
        endTimeInSeconds = clip.duration

    seg = clip.subclip(startTimeInSeconds, endTimeInSeconds).audio
    bitrate = mediainfo(inputFile)['bit_rate']
    seg.write_audiofile(outputFile, codec="libmp3lame", bitrate=bitrate)



I would suggest trying a different codec (eg. pcm_s16le), or using the ffmpeg-python library perhaps.

I just tried it I still get delay. Also I can see the video track shows 2:28;17 vs 2:28;22 for the extracted audio. I didnt try ffmpeg-python but I called ffmpeg using subprocess but it was the same. I was extracting only a small portion. I mean they both matched as I assume moviepy uses ffmpeg behind the scenes.

I'm not that familiar with the moviepy.editor library, although if you want to try a few other things this gist might be of some use: https://gist.github.com/ParityError/63c74bb424df5480a67f7d67a6f10320

Could it be the start offset of the input stream being non-zero?

@kesh how to set it to 0? i didnt alter anything

What I meant is the stored start time of each stream in your video file. (Often omitted if 0.) You can add the output of ffprobe or other media probe tool to your post.

@l'L'l i just tried it but same result as before. so maybe ffmpeg itself has the issue.

@kesh i use the function here with 0 to 100 seconds still same issue: https://gist.github.com/ParityError/63c74bb424df5480a67f7d67a6f10320

The audio could be offset in the video file.  In any case, MP3 isn't suitable if you require such accurate timing, without a container to set the offset.  (Check out the "gapless MP3" problem.)  It's also not clear at all why you care about the timing... if you're extracting the audio, why does it matter if it's still relative to the video?

@Brad because i am using this audio as a reference to match another track. So it needs to align with what the video shows.

@Brad Also I used wav it's still the same.

As soon as you extract audio out of the video file, you lose any common frame of time reference.  So, if you want to stay relative to the video track time, don't take your audio from it.

Video editors are able to separate audio and video tracks without changing the time though, how do they do it then?
